# How do you code for a 'not equivalent' sign in TeX?

Tags: symbols

I can get the not equal to sign, but can't seem to find the not equivalent sign!

Comment: How about `$\not\equiv$`  ?

Comment: Of course it had to be blindingly obvious, thank you!

Comment: @Philipp Imhof, short answers are answer too, so why post it as a comment?

Answer (score 23):

You can use `$\not\equiv$`.

And you can always have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Or you try [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) where you can draw your symbol.